# Golang scan foreign key from query response

Tags: go

I select all rows from a table that has a foreign key `status_fk`, but when I do a scan it always return 0:

```
  q := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM task WHERE user_fk = %v AND status_fk = %v", account.ID, r.FormValue("key"))
    response, err := db.Query(q)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
 for response.Next() {
   response.Scan(&tempTask.Title, &tempTask.Status)
}
```

`tempTask.Status` is a struct that is suppose take the values of the foreign key, but the properties of that struct is always 0.

I also tried to just create a variable that will take the value of the actual foreign which is just an ID. But the value is still 0

```
var statusKey int

response.Scan(&tempTask.Title, &statusKey)
```

Comment: Check the error returned from `response.Scan` and update the question with the contents of that error.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong data type, it's type `uint` instead of `int`